# onTextChanged() method called without calling setText() or user's typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

`TextWatcher` works fine until my activity is destroyed and before restoring from old saved bundle. But when I restore from saved bundle `onTextChanged()` is called for both of my EditTexts. This happens even if I don't restore their values (don't call setText()). Note that user is not interacting in any way.

**Code :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_trip);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    fromLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from_location);
    toLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to_location);

    // Set EditTexts listeners
    setFromLocationEditTextListeres();
    setToLocationEditTextListeres();

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Restoring state from saved bundle");
        ...

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Setting default values");
        ... 
    }
}


// Set listener for fromLocation EditText
private void setFromLocationEditTextListeres() {

    fromLocation.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                Log.d(TAG, "fromLocation gained focus.");

            }
        }
    });

    fromLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Fromlocation after.");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if (fromLocation == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "fromLocation is null................");
            }

            if (count != before) {
                editTextValueChanged(fromLocation);
            }
        }
    });

    fromLocation.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // If user pressed enter
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            }

            // If pressed other than enter key then let others handle the
            // event
            return false;
        }
    });
}

// Set listener for toLocation EditText
private void setToLocationEditTextListeres() {

    toLocation.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                Log.d(TAG, "toLocation gained focus.");
            }
        }
    });

    toLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Tolocation after.");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if (count != before) {
                editTextValueChanged(toLocation);
            }
        }
    });

    toLocation.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // If user pressed enter
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            }

            // If pressed other than enter key then let others handle the
            // event
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState called.");

    // Save activity state
    savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(FROM_LOCATION_TEXT,
            fromLocation.getText());
    savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(TO_LOCATION_TEXT,
            toLocation.getText());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: @kcoppock Sorry for that. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After headache of few hours the reason of issue comes out to be my following code :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState called.");

    // Save activity state
    savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(FROM_LOCATION_TEXT,
            fromLocation.getText());
    savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(TO_LOCATION_TEXT,
            toLocation.getText());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

What happens is android itself stores my `EditText`'s state (if `id` attribute is specified in layout file) and when activity is restored using saved bundle it restores EditText's value by calling `myEditText.setText()`. This was triggering call to text changed listeners.

Solution is removing lines from above code which saves `EditText`'s text. Do not save `EditText` or similar `View`'s state explicitly. Let android do it for you.

Comment: how does android knows what is being saved, it could have been anything. I don't understand how the above lines affects the saved instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that you first `@Override` the `onTextChanged()` in `fromLocation.addTextChangedListener` and then you `@Override` it once more inside of `toLocation.addTextChangedListener`. Then in the `onCreate` inside of `if (savedInstanceState != null) {` you have:

```
 fromLocation.setText(savedInstanceState
 .getCharSequence(FROM_LOCATION_TEXT));
 toLocation.setText(savedInstanceState
 .getCharSequence(TO_LOCATION_TEXT));
```

Which triggers both mentioned `addTextChangedListener`s.

EDIT (following the update of the question):

In the `onCreate` you call this, before any `if` statements:

```
// Set EditTexts listeners
setFromLocationEditTextListeres();
setToLocationEditTextListeres();
```

Then you have:

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState called.");

// Save activity state
savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(FROM_LOCATION_TEXT,
        fromLocation.getText());
savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(TO_LOCATION_TEXT,
        toLocation.getText());
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
```

}

So, you're restoring the text in the EditTexts from here above, then in the `onCreate` you set the listeners - thus setting the text on the `EditTexts` triggers the `onTextChanged` for bothe the `EditTexts`. Afterwards in the `onCreate` method you have:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Restoring state from saved bundle");
    // Restore value of members from saved state

    .../*Intentionnaly missed part*/
     fromLocation.setText(savedInstanceState
     .getCharSequence(FROM_LOCATION_TEXT)); <- Here you set the text again and trigger the `onTextChanged` 
    .../*Intentionnaly missed part*/
     toLocation.setText(savedInstanceState
     .getCharSequence(TO_LOCATION_TEXT)); <- Here you set the text again and trigger the `onTextChanged

} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Setting default values");
    .../*Intentionnaly missed part*/
    fromLocation.setText("Hello");<- Here you set the text again and trigger the `onTextChanged
}
```

I think that the described behaviour (e.g. "TextWatcher works fine until my activity is destroyed and before restoring from old saved bundle. But when I restore from saved bundle onTextChanged() is called for both of my EditTexts. This happens even if I don't restore their values (don't call setText()). Note that user is not interacting in any way.") happens only in the case of `fromLocation` (`EditText`) and not in both the cases (e.g. `fromLocation` and `toLocation`).

To finish this - you have also lots and lots of flags, which I don't even know what are they used for. To underline also the function `editTextGainedFocus(EditText)` which is not described here.

Cheers.

Comment: But both listeners listen to separate EditTexts. And listener for both of them is called twice.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this before you updated the Question. Let me check what can be wrong with this explanation.

Comment: If the answer differs from the explanations I've given, then post the answer as a separate post and accept it.